# Attaching an Event Listener

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I've just finished creating a meticulously generated grid of icons (imageViews) and now I need to be able to do something with them. What I'm finding, though, is that the event listener I'm trying to bind isn't getting bound. Window loads, my icons are displayed nicely, but they aren't clickable.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? The code below is a fully functional (except for the part that doesn't function) file. You should be able to copy it into a test app and load it right up (may be iPhone-only at the moment).

Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    layout: 'vertical',
    navBarHidden: true,
});

// icon grid
var icons = [
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Hospital Locations', url: 'http://google.com' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Tobacco Free Campus', url: 'http:://robwilkerson.org' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'ER Wait Times', url: 'http://letmegooglethatforyou.com' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Make a Donation', url: 'http://flickr.com/photos/robwilkerson' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Condition Search', url: 'http://facebook.com' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Video Library', url: 'http://google.com/reader' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Financial Help', url: 'http://stackoverflow.com' },
    { image: '/images/ico_generic.png', label: 'Patient Forms', url: 'http://github.com' }
];

// put the grid in a scrollable view
var iconGrid = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    layout: 'vertical',
});

// incoming properties we want customizable
var cols    = 3;
var icoW    = 57;
var icoH    = 57;

// Grid
var xSpacer    = 10; // horizontal space b/t icons
var ySpacer    = 10; // vertical space b/t icons
var rows       = Math.ceil( icons.length / cols ); // how many rows?
// Container width = 1/3 of the viewport minus the icon widths and spacers
var containerW = Math.floor( ( Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth - ( xSpacer * ( cols + 1 ) ) ) / 3 );
// Container height = icon height + label spacer + label height
var containerH = icoH + ySpacer + 15;
// Row height = icon height + top spacer + bottom spacer + label spacer + 15 (label height)
var rowH       = containerH + ( 2 * ySpacer );

// Incrementing values
var i = 0;
var viewHeight = 0;

for( var y = 0; y < rows; y++ ) {
    var thisRow = Ti.UI.createView({
        className: 'grid',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        height: rowH,
        touchEnabled: false,
    });

    viewHeight += rowH;

    for( var x = 0; x < cols && i < icons.length; x++ ) {
        var container = Ti.UI.createView({
            left: xSpacer,
            height: containerH,
            top: ySpacer,
            width: containerW,
        });
        var icon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            left: ( containerW - icoW ) / 2,
            height: icoH,
            image: icons[i].image,
            top: 0,
            width: icoW,
        });
        var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            // borderColor: '#00f',
            font: { fontSize: 12 },
            height: 15,
            text: icons[i].label,
            textAlign: 'center',
            top: icoH + ySpacer,
            width: containerW,
        });

        icon.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
            alert( 'Icon ' + i + ' was clicked' );d
        });

        container.add( icon );
        container.add( label );
        thisRow.add( container );
        i++;
    }

    iconGrid.add( thisRow );
    iconGrid.height = viewHeight;
}

win.add( iconGrid );
win.open();
```

Comment: what about the 'd' in your click event? does this cause the failure?

Comment: Whoops. That's just a typo. I did find the solution (it was a me problem) so I'll write that up after a little more testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also apply an event listener to the "view" itself. The reason being is, if you constantly add the same event listener to every single view, you'll cause the device's memory to become smaller and smaller, especially in cases where you'll have a larger data set.

My suggestion to you is this:
Add your own property to the imageView, like an "id" or something. So something like:

```
Ti.UI.createImageView({image: 'path/to/image.png', id: 'array_key'});
```

Once you've done that, you can add an event listener to the parent view, in this case your imageView.

```
view.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   alert(e.source.id + ' was clicked');
});
```

That way you have one event listener that can handle all the imageView events.

Answer (score 0):

This one's on me. In my learning process, I went through a couple of different solutions to display a grid of icons. In one of the early iterations, I had to disable touch for the row (it was a `tableView` attempt). Several iterations later I got the display right, but disabling touch access on the row killed my ability to "click" the icons.

I was so far down the road that I didn't even realize that property was still in place until a new set of eyes pointed it out to me. Once I removed that property on `thisRow`, the event listeners got bound properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some line of code. What I have done is like created the grid of images and when you click, you will be able to that image.

> {
>       "body": [
>           {
>               "type": "photo",
>               "order": 1,
>               "photos": [
>                   {
>                       "thumbnail": "http://www.flower.com/version_2.0/files/photos/thumbnails/745178756-_-1331130219.jpg",
>                       "photo": "http://www.flower.com/version_2.0/files/photos/745178756-_-1331130219.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "thumbnail": "http://www.flower.com/version_2.0/files/photos/thumbnails/58062938-_-1337463040.jpg",
>                       "photo": "http://www.flower.com/version_2.0/files/photos/58062938-_-1337463040.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "thumbnail": "http://www.flower.com/version_2.0/files/photos/thumbnails/1368715237-_-1337463149.jpg",
>                       "photo": "http://www.flower.comversion_2.0/files/photos/1368715237-_-1337463149.jpg"
>                   },
>                ]
>           },
>       ],
>       "status": true
>
> }

It was response I was getting from the server.

Now for Making it is in grid and for clickable image, I am going to paste the code below. Note grid is done for 320 px width.

> var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
>   onload : function(e) {
>
> ```
>   var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
>   var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(response);
>   Titanium.API.info('myObjectString--->: ' + myObjectString) 
>     var myArray = response.body; 
>     var objectArray = [];
>   var k = 5;  
> for (var i = 0; i < myArray[0].photos.length/5; i++)         { 
>                   var l = 0+i*5;          var m = 0           for (var j = l; j < k; j++)             {
>
>                   var thumb = Ti.UI.createImageView({  
>                       image:myArray[0].photos[j].thumbnail, 
>                       largeImage:myArray[0].photos[j].photo,
>                       height:60,
>                       tag:j,
>                       width:60, 
>                       top:5*(i+1)+60*i,
>                       left:3*(m+1)+60*m, 
>                   });
>                   objectArray.push(thumb);
>                    m++;
>                   scroll.add(thumb); 
>                   thumb.addEventListener('click' ,function(e)
>                    {
>
>                        for(var i =0;i<objectArray.length;i++)
>                        {
>                           if(e.source.tag==objectArray[i].tag)
>                           {
>
>                               var LargeImageView = Ti.UI.createWindow({
>                               backButtonTitle:'Image',
>                               barColor:'#000',
>                               backgroundColor: '#fff',
>                               backgroundImage:'./Images/background.png',
>                               url:'/More/DetailsImage.js',
>                               image:objectArray[i].largeImage,
>                               ImageArray:objectArray,
>                               index:i,
>                               });              
>                               Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(LargeImageView,{animated:true,modal:true});
>                               break;                                  
>                           }
>                        }
>
>
>
>                   });             }           l=k+5;          k=k+5;
>
>
> }          }   });
> ```